# Attach remote debugger to cloud run from Intellij

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-debugger, google-cloud-code

I have an app running on Cloud Run and I'm trying to debug remotely using Intellij and the Cloud Code plugin. The java agent is running and I'm able to create snapshots on the GCP Debugger, but Intellij won't attach to the remote code. It shows my project and target properly but gives me this warning saying "Unknown repositories are not supported." and nothing happens if I click on "Attach Anyway".

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e16ez.png)

Obs: I'm using Kotlin. Could this be the problem?

Comment: What is "this warning"? All errors need to be in your question itself as text, not buried in images.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm really sorry. I've just edited my question

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/3054 . You might consider adding info to that GH issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.